# Text box data getting cleared, when I click on check box

Tags: c#, asp.net

Text box data getting cleared, when I click on check box. I am not using update panel.When I click on check box, the page refresh and textbox value getting clared. Kindly help me. My check box is

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chckaddress" Text="Same As Above" runat="server" TextAlign="Left" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chckaddress_CheckedChanged1" />
```

Check box change event is

```
protected void chckaddress_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    if (chckaddress.Checked==true)
    {
        txtaddressL1.Text = txtaddress21.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        txtaddress21.Text="";
    }
 }
```

Please let me know what mistake I did..

Comment: Its happening the way your code in written!!

Comment: @Nitin Varpe, kindly point out my mistake

Comment: There are two textboxes, you need to set text to both textboxes to preserve previous value

Comment: @Nitin Varpe, you mean first I should save the first text box value in a string and paas this string to second text box..right??

Comment: @Nitin Varpe, but the problem is after page refresh ,text box data getting cleared..Why it happens??

Comment: Shouldn't `txtaddressL1` be `txtaddress21` ? You have 2 different textboxes...

Comment: Give more detail(code) of aspx page

Comment: else
    {
        txtaddressL1.Text="";
    }

Comment: @ Nitin Varpe, Yes I solved it through ur way

Comment: Set enableviewstate property of textbox "true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need just to change the places of the textbox,
in your code is

```
txtaddressL1.Text = txtaddress21.Text;
```

---

Just change it

```
txtaddress21.Text = txtaddressL1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just write a check for postback

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         if (IsPostBack)
             return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like code is good.. the only problem what I can see that txtaddress21.Text don't have any value. that's why it's getting blank each time, doesn't matter if you have checked or unchecked the checkbox.